# How to load custom dataset into keras instead of cifar10?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, dataset, tf.keras

I am getting into Neural networks and image recognition in python and followed [this guide](https://stackabuse.com/image-recognition-in-python-with-tensorflow-and-keras/).
They use:`from keras.datasets import cifar10` to get the images for the testing. So my questions are:

- how do i import a custom dataset with my own local images?
- How would i structure the files for it to load correctly?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way to load your dataset for training or testing is by using Keras [ImageDataGenerator](https://keras.io/api/preprocessing/image/) class (that also allows you some data augmentation methods). You have 3 options :

- If your dataset is structured like this :

  ```
   data/
     train/
       dogs/
         dog001.jpg
         dog002.jpg
         ...
       cats/
         cat001.jpg
         cat002.jpg
         ...
     validation/
       dogs/
         dog001.jpg
         dog002.jpg
         ...
       cats/
         cat001.jpg
         cat002.jpg
         ...
  ```

Then you should use `.flow_from_directory(directory)`. A really good example is provided [here](https://studymachinelearning.com/keras-imagedatagenerator-with-flow_from_directory/).

- If your entire dataset can be loaded into a single array (which implies that your dataset is quite small, otherwise your RAM will explode), you should go for the `.flow()` function. Example [here](https://studymachinelearning.com/keras-imagedatagenerator-with-flow/).
- You can also use a `pandas DataFrame` to store informations (such as paths, labels...) of each of your samples, that way the proper function would be `.flow_from_dataframe(df)`. See [here](https://studymachinelearning.com/keras-imagedatagenerator-with-flow_from_dataframe/) for a detailed example.

Lastly, if none of these functions can be applied (that can be the case for example if you have a huge dataset -implying you have to work with images paths- and quite unorthodox labels -preventing you from using `.flow_from_directory()` or `.flow_from_dataframe()` methods-, or simply if you just want to apply some more powerful data augmentation), then you should create a custom Data Generator. You can see [here](https://stanford.edu/%7Eshervine/blog/keras-how-to-generate-data-on-the-fly) and [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/keras-data-generators-and-how-to-use-them-b69129ed779c) examples of how to create such, and [there](https://www.kaggle.com/mpalermo/keras-pipeline-custom-generator-imgaug) is an example of one using [Imgaug](https://github.com/aleju/imgaug) for data augmentation.

There's plenty of documentation and examples online, so you should not have trouble finding what's best for you.

Comment: Thank you very much! This looks like the exakt information i needed!!!

Comment: You're welcome! If this answer fit your question and thoughts, I'd appreciate you validate it ;)